# Importar páginas desde Word con Ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ms-word

Estoy comenzando con Ckeditor 5 y he estado probando su funcionamiento, aunque me parece mejor que otros editores wysiwyg e importa desde Word. He estado intentando copiar en dicho wysiwyg un fichero con varias páginas. Si voy página a página se copia bien (aunque yo quería cargar los encabezamientos y los pies de página), ahora cuando intento copiar varias páginas ocurre que las imágenes o los gráficos no se ven, es como si no se importaran en el pegado. Total que tras revisar el GitHub del proyecto no acabo de tener claro si es que no tiene soporte para varias páginas o que estoy haciendo algo de manera incorrecta. El código con el que llamo al CKEDITOR es el siguiente:

```
<textarea name="body" id="editor1" rows="40" cols="80">
            <?php if($id == "") { ?>
            <div id="imagen">
                <img src="img/Banner_2.png">
            </div>
            <div id="encabezamiento_procedimiento">

                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Titulo:  </label></td>
                        <td style="width: 200px;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Fecha:   </label></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Código: </label></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Edición: </label></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Revisión: </label></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                <table>
                <?php }else{ echo $procedimiento[0]['Documento'];} ?>

            </div>
        </textarea>
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
                //uiColor: '#E11A10'
                language: 'es'
            });
        </script>
```

Entonces, mi pregunta concreta es si alguien ve algún tipo de error en mi código o sabe de algún pluggin que haya que instalar a mayores para lo que busco.

Un saludo y gracias a todos

Comment: Puntualizar, que el código que he puesto es la versión 4, pero haciendo los cambios para el 5 tampoco funciona.

Comment: Ya que esto parece que está más o menos claro que más o menos funciona bien. Sería posible incrustar un archivo de Word (me podría valer tanto .doc como .rtf) en dicho editar y además ser editable. He probado con Google Docs, pero al hacerlo embebido no me deja modificarlo.